# How to validate credentials with user created table and generate Token in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I am new to WEB API ,here I need to implement a token based authentication for a login page .

As of now I have completed the token generate functions by providing static values for learning purpose .

Now What I want to do is I want to validate each request with the table which I have created in my SQL SERVER (LOGIN_TABLE) and generate Token **instead** of validate with **Identity tables** in web API.

Columns of LOGIN_TABLE

**FirstName,LastName,UserName,Email,Password,CreationDate**

I don't know is it possible or not ,if possible please help me to do that .

I have created my project as Web API template without MVC and choosed No Authentication then I have added all the necessary packages and classes.

Here I have added the code I have used to generate token based on the static values.

My_Controller.cs

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/data/authenticate")]
public IHttpActionResult GetForAuthenticate()
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    return Ok("Hello" + identity.Name);
}
```

MyAutorizationServerProvider.cs

```
 public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider :OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
                context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "123")
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "USER"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Sakthi"));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }else
            {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888

            //This enable cors orgin requests
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                Provider = myProvider

            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }
    }
```

AuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute :System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actioncontext)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actioncontext);
            }else
            {
                actioncontext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }

        }
    }
```

I am new to web API if I did any mistakes here please guide me to correct it .
Thanks .